# R: How to create output tables in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

have been stuck on this point for a while so I will ask here.
I have a table (Data) with a lot of info for a few years.
In this table I have column Year = ...-2018-2019-2020

What I want to do (ideally in a for loop) is creating from this table a series of tables for every year, so to have at the end something lik:

```
DB_2018 = all info from Data for year 2018
DB_2019 = similar
DB_... = same principle
```

I tried with:

```r
years = c(2018,2019,2020) ##defining the years to loop 
DB = list() ##creating empty list
for (i in years){
  DB[[i]] = as.data.table(Data[`year` == i,])
}
```

Not working though, it's just creating a list of 2020 empty elements.

Any help for this please?
Grazie

Comment: I think you can replace all of your code with just `DB <- split(Data, Data$year)`. However, why do you need to split the `data.table` into a list of `data.table`? Generally, if you want to do something to each year at a time, then you can do `Data[, (somefunc), by=.(year)]`.

Comment: As to your question, though, `for (i in years)` starts with `i <- 2018`, and then you are trying to assign to `DB[[2018]]` instead of `DB[[1]]`. You might prefer `for (i in seq_along(years)) DB[[i]] <- as.data.table(Data[\`year\` == years[i],])`.

Comment: Hey thanks r2evans! I tried and both your suggestions are very useful